# handlebars - how to access first element of child array?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have an data object, which contains an array within an array, I want to loop over the parent array and read out the first object of each child array.

In the example I want to read out: {"id":1}, {"id":9}, {"id":11}

```
var object = 
{ parts: [ [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}], [{"id":9},...], [{"id":11},... ] ] }
```

so far I have a for each loop:

```
        {{#each object.parts}} ...  {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to get the first element, you would need:

```
{{#each object.parts}}
    {{this.[0]}}
{{/each}}
```

but this would just print [object object].

The second requirement - viewing it as JSON - requires a helper in your JS:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('json', function(context) {
    return JSON.stringify(context);
});
```

and then:

```
{{#each object.parts}}
    {{json this.[0]}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: it does not work, have you tried it? also this[0].id does not work

Comment: This works for me with `this.[0]`.